# Access driver for a specific shape key

Tags: python, drivers, shape-keys

I know of this API:

```
drivers = bpy.data.shape_keys['Key.002'].animation_data.drivers
```

But it gives all the drivers in the collection. What I need is the driver for single shape key, something like:

```
shape_key = bpy.data.shape_keys['Key.002'].key_blocks['head_leagth']
shape_key.animation_data.drivers # Doesn't work. How to get the driver of this shape key?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial & error, I came up with this solutio:

```
def get_driver_of_shape_key(shape_key):
    key = shape_key.id_data
    p = re.compile(r'key_blocks\["(.+)"\]')
    fcurves = key.animation_data.drivers
    for f in fcurves:
        m = p.search(f.data_path)
        if m and m[1] == shape_key.name:
            return f.driver
    return None
```

It's rather hacky so use at your own discretion.